# Does Ubuntu 18.04 Server Raspberry Pi support hidden wireless?

Tags: server, raspberrypi

Does Ubuntu 18.04 Server Raspberry Pi support `hidden wireless`?

I try to figure out this issue for a few days.
could you give me advance. thanks

1)/etc/netplan/`50-cloud-init.yam` <- I don't have any idea to set hidden wifi.

```
network: 
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.31/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
      access-points:
        myssid: {password: mypasswork}
      ###no any idea for hidden wifi###
```

2)/etc/network/interfaces <- not working

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.31
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.254
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

---

```
network={
    ssid="myssid"
    scan_ssid=1
    psk="mypassword"
}
```

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111494/netplan-not-connecting-to-hidden-ssid-server-18-04-1-lts