# How to connect Raspberry Pi 4 to a hidden WiFi network on Ubuntu Server 20.04?

Tags: networking, server, wireless, network-manager, raspberrypi

I have a Raspberry Py 4 with Ubuntu Server 20.04. I want to setup a WiFi connection on it. I have two WiFi networks (2.4 ghz and 5 ghz), both are hidden and have WPA2-Personal setup.

In my `/etc/netpaln/50-cloud-init.yaml` I have the following config:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            optional: true
            access-points:
                "MY_HIDEN_SID":
                    password: "MY_PASSWORD"
            dhcp4: true
```

Unfortunately, network connection does not work. However, if I setup a mobile hotspot on my phone and change SID and password it connects successfully. So the reason must be in hidden network.

**Question:**  How to connect Raspberry Pi 4 to a hidden WiFi network on Ubuntu Server 20.04?

**UPDATE:** *It turns out [there is an option](https://netplan.io/reference/) in `netplan` to specify hidden networks. But it is available only from version 0.100. At the same time, it is not possible to identify which version is included into the 20.20 distribution (it is not the latest one) because netplan developers [removed](https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/netplan/commit/9ea105bef2cea28916213aad93a37ea85d89fdbc) version information from the "netplan info" output.*

**UPDATE 2** [This hack](https://askubuntu.com/a/1117550/710246) helped solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**netplan**

.yaml files are very fussy with the formatting.

Use this .yaml, and keep the spacing, indentation, and no tabs exactly the same... edit in your SSID and password...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      #hidden: true # only in netplan 0.100
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "MYREALSSID\"\n  scan_ssid=1\n# \"hack!":
          password: "MY_PASSWORD"
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplay apply`

**wpasupplicant**

Ubuntu Server does not come with `wpasupplicant` installed, and it's required for wireless to work. We'll install it. A working ethernet connection is required, or a USB flash drive.

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant`

`reboot`

**Update #1:**

A hack to get hidden networks to work is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111494/netplan-not-connecting-to-hidden-ssid-server-18-04-1-lts/1117550#1117550).

Comment: Well, as I mentioned already, my configuration works well. The issue is it doesn't work with hidden networks.

Comment: @SashaShpota  You said *"network connection does not work"*. Does it work when you remove `optional: true` from the wifis stanza? Did you install wpasupplicant?

Comment: If I remove `optional: true` it blocks the startup. No, I have not installed wpasupplicant.

Comment: @SashaShpota `optional: true` only fails (for a specific amount of time) because the network connection can't be made. Install `wpasupplicant` and try again... as per my answer.

Comment: Turns out `wpasupplicant` was already a part of the distribution. Any other ideas?

Comment: Found a workaround using this hack https://askubuntu.com/a/1117550/710246

Comment: @SashaShpota  Wow! Great!

Comment: I'll add that to my answer!

Answer (score 0):

The correct format of the netplan file for hidden SSIDs on 20.04 is:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            optional: true
            access-points:
                "MY_HIDEN_SID":
                    password: "MY_PASSWORD"
                    hidden: true
            dhcp4: true
```